# DataInputStream.readInt() returns EOFException when connection is made immediately and no data has been transferred

Tags: java, android, kotlin, sockets

I'm implementing a 2-way file transfer between the server (Java FX) application and the client (A mobile application). File transfer from the JavaFX to the mobile app is successful, however when I tried to send files from the mobile app to the JavaFX application, I get an EOFException immediately I connect even when no files have been sent from the mobile app.

However, whenever I commented out the function used for receiving files from the JavaFX application, no error is thrown. I don't know, but it seems both inputStreams and outputStreams of both applications seem to clash or maybe there's something I am missing. I have googled this error all to no avail.

Minimal reproducible example of Server Code:

```
import java.io.DataOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.ServerSocket;
import java.net.Socket;
import java.nio.charset.StandardCharsets;

public class Server {
    DataOutputStream dataOutputStream;
    DataInputStream dataInputStream;

    public Server(){
        try{
            int port = 19051;
            ServerSocket serverSocket = new ServerSocket(port);

            while (true){

                Socket socket = serverSocket.accept();

                dataInputStream = new DataInputStream(socket.getInputStream());
                dataOutputStream = new DataOutputStream(socket.getOutputStream());

                MyThread myThread = new MyThread();
                new Thread(myThread).start();
            }
        }
        catch (IOException exception){
            exception.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    class MyThread implements Runnable{

        @Override
        public void run() {
            receiveFilesFromClient();
        }
    }

    public void receiveFilesFromClient(){
        try {
            int fileCount = dataInputStream.readInt();

            for (int i = 0; i < fileCount; ++i) {
                String filename;
                byte[] fileContentBytes;

                int fileNameLength = dataInputStream.readInt();
                if (fileNameLength > 0) {
                    byte[] fileNameBytes = new byte[fileNameLength];
                    dataInputStream.readFully(fileNameBytes, 0, fileNameLength);
                    filename = new String(fileNameBytes, StandardCharsets.UTF_8);

                    int fileContentLength = dataInputStream.readInt();
                    if (fileContentLength > 0) {
                        fileContentBytes = new byte[fileContentLength];
                        dataInputStream.readFully(fileContentBytes, 0, fileContentBytes.length);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        catch (IOException exception){
            exception.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Minimal reproducible example for the mobile app:

```
import android.Manifest
import android.app.Activity
import android.content.Intent
import android.content.pm.PackageManager
import android.net.Uri
import android.os.Build
import android.os.Bundle
import android.os.Environment
import android.os.StrictMode
import android.provider.OpenableColumns
import android.util.Log
import android.view.Menu
import android.view.MenuItem
import android.widget.Button
import androidx.annotation.RequiresApi
import androidx.appcompat.app.AlertDialog
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity
import androidx.core.app.ActivityCompat
import java.io.*
import java.net.InetSocketAddress
import java.net.Socket


private const val REQUEST_EXTERNAL_STORAGE = 1
private const val CHOOSE_FILES = 1000
private const val TAG = "SendReceiveFileActivity"
class SendReceiveFileActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    private var ip: String? = null
    private var port: Int? = null
    var clientSocket: Socket? = null
    private lateinit var myThread: MyThread
    private lateinit var sendButton: Button
    private var dataInputStream: DataInputStream? = null
    private var dataOutputStream: DataOutputStream? = null

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_send_receive_file)

        val policy = StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder().permitAll().build()
        StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(policy)

        ip = intent.getStringExtra("ip")
        port = intent.getStringExtra("port")?.toInt()

        verifyStoragePermissions(this)

        sendButton = findViewById(R.id.btnSend)

        sendButton.setOnClickListener {
            val intent = Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT)
            intent.type = "*/*"
            intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_ALLOW_MULTIPLE, true)
            startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(intent, "Choose Files"), CHOOSE_FILES)
        }

        myThread = MyThread()
        Thread(myThread).start()
    }

    override fun onActivityResult(requestCode: Int, resultCode: Int, data: Intent?) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data)
        if (requestCode == CHOOSE_FILES) {
            if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
                if (data!!.clipData != null) {
                    val count = data.clipData!!.itemCount
                    var currentItem = 0
                    dataOutputStream?.writeInt(count)
                    while (currentItem < count) {
                        val uri = data.clipData!!.getItemAt(currentItem).uri
                        val fileInfo = getDataFromUri(uri)
                        sendFiles(uri, fileInfo)

                        currentItem += 1
                    }
                }
                else if (data.data != null) {
                    val uri = data.data!!
                    val fileInfo = getDataFromUri(uri)
                    sendFiles(uri, fileInfo)
                }
            }
        }
    }

    private fun getDataFromUri(uri: Uri): Pair<String, Long>{
        val cursor = contentResolver.query(uri, null, null,
            null, null)
        val nameIndex = cursor?.getColumnIndex(OpenableColumns.DISPLAY_NAME)!!
        val sizeIndex = cursor.getColumnIndex(OpenableColumns.SIZE)
        cursor.moveToFirst()
        val name = cursor.getString(nameIndex)
        val size = cursor.getLong(sizeIndex)
        cursor.close()
        return Pair(name, size)
    }

    private fun sendFiles(uri: Uri, fileInfo: Pair<String, Long>){
        try {
            val inputStream = contentResolver.openInputStream(uri)
            val fileName = fileInfo.first
            Log.d(TAG, "File $fileName sent")
            val fileNameBytes = fileName.toByteArray(Charsets.UTF_8)
            val fileContentBytes = ByteArray(fileInfo.second.toInt())
            inputStream!!.read(fileContentBytes)
            dataOutputStream?.writeInt(fileNameBytes.size)
            dataOutputStream?.write(fileNameBytes)
            dataOutputStream?.writeInt(fileContentBytes.size)
            dataOutputStream?.write(fileContentBytes)
            dataOutputStream?.flush()

        } catch (exception: IOException) {
            exception.printStackTrace()
        }
    }

    inner class MyThread: Runnable {

        override fun run() {
            clientSocket = Socket()
            clientSocket?.connect(port?.let { InetSocketAddress(ip, it) }, 5000)
            Log.d(TAG, "Socket Connected")

            dataInputStream = DataInputStream(clientSocket?.getInputStream())
            dataOutputStream = DataOutputStream(clientSocket?.getOutputStream())

            while (true){
                val fileNameLength = dataInputStream?.readInt()

                if (fileNameLength!! > 0){
                    val fileNameBytes = ByteArray(fileNameLength)
                    dataInputStream?.readFully(fileNameBytes, 0, fileNameLength)
                    val filename = String(fileNameBytes)

                    val fileContentLength = dataInputStream?.readInt()
                    if (fileContentLength!! > 0){
                        val fileContent = ByteArray(fileContentLength)
                        dataInputStream?.readFully(fileContent, 0, fileContentLength)
                        //downloadFile(filename, fileContent)
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The error message which is continually displayed in the logcat because of the loop is this:

```
java.io.EOFException
    at java.base/java.io.DataInputStream.readInt(DataInputStream.java:397)
    at com.sirdave.Controller.receiveFileFromClient(Controller.java:208)
    at com.sirdave.Controller$MyThread.run(Controller.java:174)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834)
java.io.EOFException
```

Comment: [mcve] please ..

Comment: `int fileNameLength = dataInputStream.readInt();` Have you checked if this is the same lenght as the client sent? The same for the content lenght.

Comment: If you have a crash then the logcat should tell you which exception you did not catch.

Comment: @blackapps, yes it is. And that is what is causing the EOF exception. Not exactly a crash, but files are not being transferred if I keep getting that exception in my logcat.

Comment: DId you answer my first comment?

Comment: Please post the relevant lines from the lgcat.

Comment: @blackapps, I answered your first comment which is that it is the same length as that sent by the client.

Comment: Also, I've added the lines from my logcat. I should however let you know that I get that exception immediately my server and client are connected, even when no files have been transferred yet. Which is the exact bug I haven't figured why yet.

Comment: `inputStream!!.read(fileContentBytes)` Does it read as much bytes as can be put in that buffer? Dont think so. Try `val nread = inputStream!!.read(fileContentBytes)` and check.

Comment: Pretty strange you still did not react on an answer you got 14 hours ago.

Comment: @SirDave then you need to [edit] your question to provide a minimal reproducible example showing how you are using these connections.

Answer (score 0):

Your client is sending only 1 file (but the function name is plural!). Does it disconnect afterward?

The server is looping endlessly to read multiple files (but the function name is singular!).

If the client disconnects after sending, it makes perfect sense why the receiving code would then throw an EOF error.

If you want to leave the connection open, either:

- get rid of the reading loop in the server and just read 1 file at a time, to match the client sending 1 file at a time:

  server:

  ```java
  public void receiveFileFromClient(){
      try {
          String filename;
          byte[] fileContentBytes;

          int fileNameLength = dataInputStream.readInt();
          if (fileNameLength > 0) {
              byte[] fileNameBytes = new byte[fileNameLength];
              dataInputStream.readFully(fileNameBytes, 0, fileNameLength);
              filename = new String(fileNameBytes, StandardCharset.UTF_8);
          }

          int fileContentLength = dataInputStream.readInt();
          if (fileContentLength > 0) {
              fileContentBytes = new byte[fileContentLength];
              dataInputStream.readFully(fileContentBytes, 0, fileContentBytes.length);
          }

          System.out.println("File name received is " + filename);
          //downloadFile(filename, fileContentBytes);
      }
      catch (IOException exception){
          exception.printStackTrace();
      }
  }
  ```

  client:

  ```
  private fun sendFile(uri: Uri, fileInfo: Pair<String, Long>){
      try {
          val inputStream = contentResolver.openInputStream(uri)
          //val fileInputStream = FileInputStream(file.absolutePath)
          val fileName = fileInfo.first
          val fileNameBytes = fileName.toByteArray(Charsets.UTF_8)
          val fileContentBytes = ByteArray(fileInfo.second.toInt())
          //val num: Int = fileInputStream.read(fileContentBytes)
          inputStream!!.read(fileContentBytes)
          dataOutputStream?.writeInt(fileNameBytes.size)
          dataOutputStream?.write(fileNameBytes)
          dataOutputStream?.writeInt(fileContentBytes.size)
          dataOutputStream?.write(fileContentBytes)
          dataOutputStream?.flush()
      } catch (exception: IOException) {
          exception.printStackTrace()
      }
  }
  ```
- have the client send an integer first indicating the number of files being sent, before then sending their datas, so the server knows when the stop looping:

  server:

  ```java
  public void receiveFilesFromClient(){
      try {
          int fileCount = dataInputStream.readInt();
          for (int i = 0; i < fileCount; ++i) {
              String filename;
              byte[] fileContentBytes;

              int fileNameLength = dataInputStream.readInt();
              if (fileNameLength > 0) {
                  byte[] fileNameBytes = new byte[fileNameLength];
                  dataInputStream.readFully(fileNameBytes, 0, fileNameLength);
                  filename = new String(fileNameBytes, StandardCharset.UTF_8);
              }

              int fileContentLength = dataInputStream.readInt();
              if (fileContentLength > 0) {
                  fileContentBytes = new byte[fileContentLength];
                  dataInputStream.readFully(fileContentBytes, 0, fileContentBytes.length);
              }

              System.out.println("File name received is " + filename);
              //downloadFile(filename, fileContentBytes);
          }
      }
      catch (IOException exception){
          exception.printStackTrace();
      }
  }
  ```

  client:

  ```
  private fun sendFile(uri: Uri, fileInfo: Pair<String, Long>){
      try {
          val inputStream = contentResolver.openInputStream(uri)
          //val fileInputStream = FileInputStream(file.absolutePath)
          val fileName = fileInfo.first
          val fileNameBytes = fileName.toByteArray(Charsets.UTF_8)
          val fileContentBytes = ByteArray(fileInfo.second.toInt())
          //val num: Int = fileInputStream.read(fileContentBytes)
          inputStream!!.read(fileContentBytes)
          dataOutputStream?.writeInt(1)
          dataOutputStream?.writeInt(fileNameBytes.size)
          dataOutputStream?.write(fileNameBytes)
          dataOutputStream?.writeInt(fileContentBytes.size)
          dataOutputStream?.write(fileContentBytes)
          dataOutputStream?.flush()
      } catch (exception: IOException) {
          exception.printStackTrace()
      }
  }
  ```

Comment: Thank you for your explanation. I've added the exception message from my logcat.  Following your suggestion, the exception gets thrown once after removing the loop. However l get that exception immediately my server and client are connected, even when no files have been transferred yet.

Comment: @SirDave then you need to edit your question to provide a [mcve] showing how you are using these connections.

Comment: I just did that. Could you please kindly take a look at it? My dataInputStream reads the same way on Android, but doesnt't throw any exception. However it throws an exception on the Server application.

Comment: Your server is sharing the `dataOutputStream` and `dataInputStream` variables amongst all connected clients. Those should be local variables inside of the `while` loop (as with the `socket`) and then passed into `myThread` for use. That way, each client acts on its own streams that are not shared with other clients. I would take that a step further by moving those variables inside the thread's `run()`, and then just pass in the accepted `socket` to the thread.